# Solution to simplify the installation of sharepoint Web Application

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm looking a solution on how to simplify the installation of sharepoint web application.
I have phase 1 until phase 3 which is each phase is adding a new function/ development.
All i want to do right now is, i want to simplify the installation of sharepoint web application which need a long step of installation and time.

The step of the installation is like import DBScript, configure web config, import sharepoint page and to deploy web solution.

So, from this step i want to minimize the step or maybe it can create like dekstop application (.exe) to install it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any Installation Provider AFAIK for SharePoint customization deployment.. What you can do is add all your customization i.e. Pages, Web Parts, Event Receivers etc. into a single Visual Studio solution and make a single WSP to deploy all these solutions..

For Web.config modifications you can use [SPWebConfigModification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861909%28v=office.14%29.aspx) class, and on Feature Event Receiver, you can write the code which will update the web.config for you..

This can work as a simple installer, once you deploy the WSP and activate the features you should have all your files in SharePoint with customization, few more things you can do with Visual Studio Solution deployment:

- Deploy CSS, JS files in Layouts folder (used across Farm)
- Deploy Page Layouts
- Create Lists Definitions and List Instances
- Deploy Master Pages and apply them
- Create pages based on Page Layouts
- Visual Web Parts
- User Controls
- And the list goes on..

**UPDATE**

[Deploying Styles, JS, JQuery, Fonts etc. in Style Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2009/11/23/how-to-deploy-a-style-sheet-into-content-library-using-visual-studio-2010-beta-2.aspx?Redirected=true)

[Deploying Master Pages, Themes using Visual Studio](http://tommdaly.wordpress.com/2011/10/22/deploying-master-pages-themes-via-a-feature-using-visual-studio-2010/) - This deploys CSS files in Layouts folder

[Deploying Master Pages and Page Layouts using Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobgerman/archive/2011/01/31/packaging-master-pages-and-page-layouts-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Comment: Can you explain to me how can i add all the customization into a single Visual studio solution and make a single WSP? Thanks again..

Comment: @Maria check the update, you can search on the internet and will find tons of examples.. You might need to write some code for deploying some artifacts, such as creating default pages based on Page Layouts!

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it was helpful :)